# Using LZMA SDK in C++

Tags: c++, 7zip, lzma

Can i use LZMA SDK in my application without using any dll libraries such as 7z.dll or 7za.dll so that my application's executable file should not have any dependencies?

If it is impossible where can i download 7z.dll/7za.dll? I downloaded LZMA from7-zip.org.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot because of 7zip LGPL license. You can have your source closed using LGPL parts but you have to provide an ability to upgrade LGPL part, usually using it as separate DLL.

You can build these DLLs from sources

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by static linking the lib into your executable, but according to its license, your code will have to be open source as well if you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can statically include/link the LZMA SDK within your application. In fact the SDK includes a pre-built executable called lzma.exe with no external LZMA dependencies.

In regards to licensing, while 7-Zip is distributed under the GNU LGPL, the LZMA SDK is **public domain**. Allowing for unrestricted reproduction and usage, although it is common courtesy to give credit where credit is due.